# Directed spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Consider a directed graph. Is there any theorem on minimum number of outgoing or incoming links for each node of digraph that guarantees the existence of directed spanning tree?

Comment: http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac96web.pdf is a paper that counts the number of directed spanning trees. Maybe if you analyze it (or some of the papers in the references) it will tell you how to decide whether there is a directed spanning tree.

Comment: Thanks I will go through the paper. Actually, I know that a digraph has directed spanning tree if and only if one of the principal minors of its in-degree Laplacian matrix be positive. In fact, it shows a globally reachable node.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this is all that is known.

Let $G$ be a digraph of order $n$. The first observation is that if the minimum semidegree $\delta^0(G)$ of $G$ (which is the minimum of the outdegree and indegree of all vertices in $G$) is less than $n/2$, then $G$ may not even be connected. (Consider for example the disjoint union of two reflexive complete digraphs of order $k$ and $k+1$, i.e., complete digraphs where each pair of vertices is joined by an edge in each direction.)

1. Ghouila-Houri has shown that if $\delta^0(G)\geq  n/2$ then $G$ contains a consistently oriented Hamilton cycle (and therefore a spanning consistently oriented path).
2. DeBiasio and Molla, and then DeBiasio, Kühn, Molla and Taylor have extended this result to the best possible bounds for all orientations of a Hamilton cycle (spoiler: it's either $\delta^0(G)\geq n/2$ or $\delta^0(G)\geq n/2+1$).

Note: the results in 2. hold for all sufficiently large $n$.

Here is the reference for the latest paper:

> Louis DeBiasio, Daniela Kühn Theodore Molla, and Amelia Taylor.
>   *Arbitrary orientations of Hamilton cycles in digraphs*.
>   SIAM Journal Discrete Mathematics 29 (2015), 1553-1584)

Answer (score 0):

There can't be such a qualifying number. Imagine a graph that meets such a threshold. Then take 3 copies of the graph and link as follows:

[image]

There is no directed spanning tree for this composite graph although it meets the assumed incoming/outgoing links criteria.

Comment: Thanks Joffan for reply.
Actually, that example came to my mind as well, BUT the issue is by copying the graph you increase the number of total nodes. Hence, the minimum number of links would change for the new graph.

Comment: I believe there exist such a condition though it might be very conservative.

Consider a digraph of three nodes, if each node has at least one out-going link that graph has directed spanning tree.

Comment: OK, I'll think about that.

Comment: I think we can look at the problem from the following perspective:

What's the maximum edges of a digraph with N nodes which doesn't have  any cycle of length N?

Comment: If the digraph is the disjoint union of tournaments, it won't be connected. To prevent this, each node must have outdegree at least...